# f:ajax (myfaces 2.0) How to get XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader in callback (onevent)?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

The [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkddf.html) tells there are no link to `XMLHttpRequest` in jsf ajax client callback (as, for example, [jQuery has](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)). How `XMLHttpRequest` or just `XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader` can be accessed in this case?

Comment: What information exactly do you need from the response header? "A lot" as indicated in a comment of yours suggests that you were abusing it for things they aren't intented for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that exactly what you want but

If you have the following code :

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="click me" id="myBtn">
        <f:ajax onevent="myFunc"/>
     </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

This is what you can extract: (debug it and find more)

```
function myFunc(data) {
    if (data.status === "success") {
        console.log(data.responseCode);
        console.log(data.responseText);
        console.log(data.responseXML);
        console.log(data.source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel! This is the point: the `data` contains some fields of `XMLHttpRequest`, but not the hole object so it is impossible to do `data.getResponseHeader(some_name)`... so there is no compability with jQuery code we want to reuse...

Comment: Why do you need the `ResponseHeader` in `f:ajax` ?

Comment: Because it is used in existed javascript code (callbacks) we would like to reuse. `ResponseHeader` contains a lot of important information for our app to run well... So this is a problem of different ajax API in jQuery and JSF (myfaces).